# Why display property set to inherit with CSS variable doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I set the display property for divs to `in
line-block`. I then created four classes:

- no-var, which sets display to `inherit`
- var, which sets display to a variable set to `inherit`
- var-none, which sets display to a variable set to `none`
- var-default, which sets display to a variable set to `inherit` and a default of `grid`

The actual style that is used by each class doesn't seem to be correct, though:

- The no-var class correctly inherits display to `block`
- The var class doesn't get the `inherit` value from the variable and displays as `inline-block`
- The var-none class correctly sets display to `none` and is hidden
- The var-default class doesn't get the `inherit` value from the variable and sets display to the default

For each of these classes I added variables and defaults for the color property, which all work as expected. Are variables supposed to ignore `inherit` and `unset` values?

```css
:root {
  --display: inherit;
  --display-none: none;
  --color: red;
}
div  {
  display: inline-block;
  color: green;
}
.no-var {
  display: inherit;
  color: red;
}
.var {
  display: var(--display);
  color: var(--color);
}
.var-none {
  display: var(--display-none);
}
.var-default {
  display: var(--display, grid);
  color: var(--color, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="no-var">
  No variable
</div>
<div class="no-var">
  No variable
</div>
<div class="var">
  Variable
</div>
<div class="var">
  Variable
</div>
<div class="var-none">
  None
</div>
<div class="var-none">
  None
</div>
<div class="var-default">
  Default
</div>
<div class="var-default">
  Default
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a value of \`inherit\` to a CSS custom property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881816/how-do-i-set-a-value-of-inherit-to-a-css-custom-property)

Comment: @chharvey you also want to close this one too :) how it's relevant in this case?. The OP is looking to understand the why and to have an explanation, he don't want to *store inherit inside a CSS variable*

Comment: @TemaniAfif In my opinion the question is a duplicate. It’s just my opinion, nothing more. If the OP can make a distinction of how it’s *not* a duplicate, that would clear things up. (By the way, he/she absolutely *does* want to store `inherit` inside a variable — the code literally contains the line `--display: inherit;`.)

Comment: @chharvey I agree with TemaniAfif. I wasn't looking for a way to get it to work, I was just trying to figure out why it wasn't working the way I thought it would. I think this question has a better explanation of why it works the way it does, too.

Comment: This one gets me every time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such situation, `inherit` is used as a value for the custom property and will not be evaluted to the `inherit` value using `var()`.

Here is a basic example to understand the issue:

```css
.box {
  --c:inherit;
  color:var(--c,red);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">I am a text</div>
</div>
<div style="--c:blue">
  <div class="box">I am a text</div>
</div>
```

Note how in the second case we have a blue color because the custom property inherited this value from the top div then it's getting evaluted to that value. In the first case, we will use the default color because there is nothing to inherit.

[image]

In other words, `inherit` will be considered for the custom property and not for the property where you will evalute the custom property using `var()`. You will not find a custom property with a computed value equal **to inherit** BUT with a computed value equal **to the inherited value**.

---

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables):

> Custom properties are **ordinary properties**, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with **the normal inheritance** and cascade rules

Comment: That's interesting and makes sense when explained like that, thank you!

Comment: @GammaGames you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239880/how-to-store-inherit-value-inside-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variables/53239881#53239881 in case you need a way to use inherit value within CSS variable

Comment: same as not declaring `--c:inherit;` in the stylesheet to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to use a property value that is 'context aware' such as `auto`, `100%` or `1em`.

For instance right now (this is for Angular material styles so I don't control all CSS) I need to set a variable corresponding to a `font-size` to prevent a default var() value being used.

So in the context of `font-size`: `100%` or `1em` effectively means the same as `inherit`.

So the Material style (that I can't change) might be something like the following (and I want to prevent their default of 18px from being used):

```
font-size: var(--mat-body-font-size, 18px)
```

and as explained by Temani I can't do this:

```
.parent-element
{
    font-size: 28px;  
    --mat-button-font-size: inherit;
}
```

Instead I can use a custom property value that behaves like 'inherit', but only because I'm using `font-size`.

```
.parent-element
{
    font-size: 28px;  
    --mat-button-font-size: 100%;
}
```

So `font-size: 100%` gets applied instead of 18px and effectively does nothing, inheriting whatever font size I've previous set in the parent.

Another example might be `--color: currentColor` for a property that is `color`.