# CSS var(--my-var, fallback) with initial value. Is it a bug?

Tags: css, css-variables

In css the var() with fallback, the *fallback should be ignored* if the `--var` exists.
But i tried set the `--var` with `initial` value then causing the `--var` no longer exists, so the fallback will be used.

I tested on chrome & firefox, resulting the same.

Is that a bug in css or it just an exception rule of fallback? I didn't see on doc in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values

```css
.test1 {
  color: var( --not-existing, red);
}

.test2 {
  --my-color: blue;
  color: var( --my-color, red);
}

.test3 {
  --my-color: initial;
  color: var( --my-color, red);
}

.test4 {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">
  I should be red
</p>

<p class="test2">
  I should be blue
</p>


<p class="test3">
  I should be initial color (not working)
</p>

<p class="test4">
  I should be initial color (works)
</p>
```

See my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-312oj?file=/index.html

Comment: this is indeed a feature of CSS variables and a useful one in case you want to re-use the fallback or simply unset the variables

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please add reference to your bold statement.

Comment: @connexo check the duplicates, I am referencing the specification

Comment: @TemaniAfif As cited, the spec clearly states *with the same meaning as in any another property*. So how can this part of the spec be correct if the algorithms are designed to work differently?

Comment: @connexo both Spec are correct. initial *apply* to the custom property and is not stored inside the custom property. Same logic with inherit (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214440/8620333)