# Inheriting Font Family with css variable not working

Tags: css, css-variables

I am trying to inherit the global font-family in a variable. However this does not work.

```css
:root {
  --special-font: sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-family: serif;
}

.highlight {
  font-family: var(--special-font);
}

.special {
  --special-font: inherit;
}


/* .special {
  --special-font: serif;
} */


/* .special .highlight {
  font-family: inherit;
} */
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>
      Standard Font: Serif
    </p>
    <p class="highlight">
      Highlight Font: Sans Serif
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <p class="highlight">
      Special Highlight: should be Serif
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Both the commented out rules would work. But I would prefer to not repeat myself. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you set up a variable, you cannot assign it another value later. Create 2 variables like `--standard-font` and `--highlight-font` and just use font-family: variable.

`:root {
        --special-font: sans-serif;
        --serif-font: serif;
    }

    html {
        font-family: var(--serif-font);
    }

    .highlight {
        font-family: var(--special-font);
    }

    .special .highlight {
        font-family: var(--serif-font);
    }``

Comment: Sorry for bad code format

Comment: @AlexandraBatrak That would be a workaround. But it is not correct, that a variable can't be changed later. If I specify `serif` instead of `inherit` in the `.special` selector, it works as expected.

Comment: You're right :D It works with `.special { --special-font: initial; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out what is happening, thanks to a comment, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239880/how-to-store-inherit-value-inside-a-css-variable-aka-custom-property) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214440/14906662). I am not actually setting the variable to contain the value `inherit` but rather tell the variable to inherit its value.

In order do make my font-family inherit the documentwide font, I can set the variable to `initial`. For a variable this is an empty string, thereby setting the `font-family` property of my paragraph to its default behaviour, which is `inherit`.