# How to store inherit value inside a CSS variable (aka custom property)?

Tags: css, css-variables

Let's consider this simplified example in order to illustrate the issue:

```css
:root {
  --color:rgba(20,20,20,0.5); /*defined as the default value*/
}

.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.red {background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);}
.blue {background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);}

.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:translateX(30px);
  background:var(--color);
  filter:invert(1);
}
```

```html
<!-- we can add any color we want -->
<div class="box red" style="--color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);">
</div>
<div class="box blue" style="--color:rgba(0,255,255,0.5);">
</div>

<!-- we can add the same color but this won't be dynamic -->
<div class="box red" style="--color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);">
</div>

<!-- it would be good to be able to inherit the value but this won't work -->
<div class="box red" style="--color:inherit;">
</div>
```

In the above code we are able to manipulate the `background` of the pseudo element using CSS variable. In some cases, we need to have the same color as the main element but since we don't know what color is used, we cannot set it manually and the best way should be to use the `inherit` value.

As explained here: [Css display property set to inherit with variable doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53213870/8620333), the use of `inherit` won't work.

Is there any way to be able to store the `inherit` value within a CSS variable and use it later within any property (`background` in our example)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In such case, we can consider the fallback value of a CSS variable. Like explained in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#using-variables) we can write something like this:

```
background:var(--color,inherit)
```

By doing this, we tell our property (`background`) to use `inherit` in case `--color` is not defined.

This may solve the issue but in our case it won't be enough since `--color` is **always** defined at `:root` level and will get inherited<sup>1</sup> by the pseudo element thus we will never use the fallback value.

To fix this we can consider the `initial` value in order to undefine our custom property and force the use of the fallback value. As described in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#syntax):

> The **initial** value of a custom property is an **empty value**; that is, nothing at all. This initial value has a special interaction with the var() notation, which is explained in the section defining var().

and

> To ***substitute a var()*** in a property’s value:
>
> 1. If the custom property named by the first argument to the var()
>      function is animation-tainted, and the var() function is being used in
>      the animation property or one of its longhands, treat the custom
>      property as having its initial value for the rest of this algorithm.
> 2. If the value of the custom property named by the first argument to the
>      var() function is anything **but the initial value**, replace the var()
>      function by the value of the corresponding custom property. Otherwise,
> 3. if the var() function **has a fallback value** as its second argument,
>      **replace the var() function by the fallback value**. If there are any
>      var() references in the fallback, substitute them as well.
> 4. Otherwise, the property containing the var() function is invalid at
>      computed-value time

Our code will then look like this:

```css
:root {
  --color:rgba(25,25,25,0.5); /*defined as the default value*/
}

.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.red {background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);}
.blue {background:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);}

.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:translateX(30px);
  background:var(--color,inherit);
  filter:invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box red" style="--color:initial;">
</div>
<div class="box blue" style="--color:initial;">
</div>

<div class="box" style="background:grey;--color:initial;">
</div>
```

We simply need to set `initial` to the custom property in order to force the `inherit` to be used as a value within `background`.

---

The usage of `initial` can also be useful in order to stop *the propagation* of CSS variable at a particular level since by default it's inherited by all the elements.

Here is an example:

```css
:root {
  --color: blue;
}
.container div{
  border:5px solid var(--color,red);
  padding:5px;
}
.stop {
  --color:initial;
}
.green {
  --color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> 
    <div>
      <div class="stop"> <!-- we stop at this level -->
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container stop"> <!-- we stop at this level -->
  <div> 
    <div>
      <div class="green">  <!-- we redefine at this level -->
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>1: it's about the inheritance of the custom property and not the background property</sup>